# Simplest way to create two private sections each with a common account

Tags: login, private

My client's site requires two separate, private sections. For each of them, there is one common login/password pair (or possibly one password without login) to be used. The client probably wants this information to be manageable in dashboard.

Since for each page the credentials are the same for everybody with access, I guess working with WP users and WP native private functionality is unnecessarily complicated. But then what would be the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: Are these multiple pages in each section, or are they single pages that need passwords? WordPress allows you to mark posts and pages as 'private' and set a password on the content which is controllable in the admin: http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Password_Protected_Content

Comment: I'm not sure yet. If one area should have multiple pages protected by the same credentials, can the solution you mention be still used?

Comment: You'd need to set the password for each page that needs to be protected; and I believe the user would need to re-enter the password for each page as they navigate around. Really anything more complicated than the single protected page I'd recommend setting up a custom role and not use the same password for everyone.

Comment: guiniveretoo: I created a pass-protected page X and then several pass-protected child pages with the same password and whose parent page is X. If I enter the password to view X, I can then view its child pages without entering the password again provided the password is the same for parent and child pages. Neat! WP apparently checks whether parent and child pages passwords are the same or not. I don't know since when this feature appeared in WP but it's cool. Thanks for directing me towards this simple solution!

Comment: Codex: "Furthermore, if multiple posts use the same password, the reader will only have to enter the password once to access every post". (http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection#Password_Protecting_Many_Posts_and_Pages)

Comment: NICE! Well I guess I learned something new today too!

Comment: I'm going to enter this info as an answer, so future users will be able to find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress allows you to mark posts and pages as 'private' and set a password on the content which is controllable in the admin:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility#Password_Protected_Content

If you set multiple pages with the same password, the user will only need to enter it once.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection#Password_Protecting_Many_Posts_and_Pages